# Array Comparison Algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Checking two integer arrays if second array contains bigger elements than each of the element of first array in C

```
a[10]={34,234,3,4,5646}
b[10]={5849,39,1,7,45}
```

How can I find out that B array contains greater than or equal element than each of the elements of A array? Is there any particular algorithm?

Comment: How would you do it using pen and paper?

Comment: Do you want to test only elements at the same index positions (e.g. b[x] > a[x] for all valid "x" index values), or are you testing whether b[x] > a[y] for all valid x and y index values?

Comment: Basically if the min of the second array is bigger than the max of the first array?

Comment: Yeah, it's a little unclear what you are asking for and, even if that was clear, what your problem is with finding it out.  You can easily find the max value of either array by iterating it.  Note that if you have five negative values initialized as above, the max. value will be 0 because of the implicit initialization of the top [5..9] values in your arrays[10] to 0.

Comment: i want to find if there is bigger element in b array for every element in a array.....for example, on the example given above,  a[0]<b[1], a[1]<b[0], a[2]<b[3],a[3]<b[4] , so a[4] has no corresponding bigger element in b array.....elements of b array must be as small as possible

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand you can find the largest element of array a in O(n) and find the smallest element of array b in O(n) and compare them